# How to Serialize in json new properties after hide it in derived class

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization

I have to parent class such as:

```
public class Title
{
    public List<Detail> details {get; set;}

}

public class Detail
{
    // some properties
}

public class TitleChild : Title
{
    public new List<DetailChild> details {get; set;}  // hiding

}

public class DetailChild : Detail
{
    // some properties
}
```

I need to serialize a list of Title `List<Title>` and list of TitleChild `List<TitleChild>`

Everythings is ok in `List<Title>` but in `List<TitleClild>` some things are wrong.
After deserializing it in javascript I notice that the details properties steel is the hidden property in the superclass.

What should I do ?

And also I can't ignore serializing on hidden property is superclass because I need it in serializing time on the superclass.

Comment: It is the same with any data: You expect a special type or the type information has to be part of the message

Answer (score 0):

Serialization most likely just traverses public properties. You have hidden your details on purpose with the `new` keyword. You can try changing the structure so that you do not use `new`. It seems rather weird in here really and you'd better avoid it in any case.

E.g. if you want both properties back, you can change the name of `details` to `childrenDetails` and remove `new`.

P.S. Since your `DetailChild` inherits from `Detail`, you can really just use the original `details` list and populate it with `DetailChild` objects.

Comment: But how should the deserializer know when to create DetailChild instances? That is the main question